# DC motor related questions

Tags: motor, dc

The voltage of my DC motor is 9V and its RPM is 200.  How much weight can it carry and move easily?

Comment: Please post a model # or a torque curve.

Comment: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31501/how-can-i-calculate-the-power-and-torque-required-for-the-motor-on-a-wheeled-rob/31502#31502 It's not difficult but takes some judgement. You have not specified or given thought to many required required parameters. Gearing, wheel diameter, and desired acceleration and speed all matter. For the torque-speed curve Voltage Spike is asking for, it is possible to generalize with DC brushed and brushless motors as long as you have the no-load RPM and stall torque. Look "DC Motor Specification" section at the very bottom of that answer.

Comment: Anywhere from nothing at all to knocking over the Eiffel tower, depending on the basic motor, how it's wound, and how much it is geared down.  Please _edit your question_ with more information.  The best information would be the model number of the motor (or motor-gearbox combination) or a torque curve.  A distant second best would be a picture of the motor sitting next to a ruler, and a discussion of how you know it makes 200 RPM from 9V.

Answer (score 1):

A motor cannot carry weight but has torque and a pulley to convert torque to a Force.

The force depends on the pulley/gear ratio and can reach 10x the rated power when it starts to move.

If it does not move the holding torque will be limited by the V+/DCR=Imax which can be 10x or more the rate current of P/V=I_rated and will also require a fan since it is not rotating and needs forced air cooling to reduce winding temp rise < 50'C.

You will need to define the physics of your problem with acceleration which affects current, load inertia (p=mv), position feedback method, and hold position error allowance from disturbances.  You will likely want to reduce speed and increase torque with built-in metal gears or external pulleys and belts.

A good Eng. friend of mine designed an elevator lift to hold 1 person 100 kg max for the patio to the basement.  He gave up :( when I showed the energy and torque required to be stable with a knee jerk for safety reasons to be stable with at least a 20 dB attenuation of the disturbance or 10x rated power.